# How to make an ASCII bell not create a newline?

Tags: python, ascii

I'm working on a game in python and I made a python function to scroll the text. I wanted to make a sound for each letter like this [Unity Tutorial - UnderTale Scrolling Text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVty-jrQh88) and found the ASCII bell alert sound was perfect. However, it creates a newline. I am doing this on a remote VM and cannot figure out how to do python sound any other way. Is there a way for it to not display a newline every `\a`?

Code:

```
def scrollTxt(str):
  for letter in str:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.06)
    print("\a")
```

Output:

```
Select your language:
1) Español 
2) English
2


E
n
g
l
i
s
h

E
n
t
e
r

y
o
u
r

n
a
m
e
```

Comment: `print("\a", end="")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `end` keyword argument of the `print` function to achieve this, like so:

```
print("\a", end="")
```

This overrides the default value of `end`, which is `\n`.